# Gzip compression on Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, compression, gzip, tomcat6

What is a difference between

> compression="on"

and

> compression="force"

?

[Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) says:

> "on" - allow compression, which causes text data to be compressed
>
> "force" - forces compression in **all cases**

What are the extra cases?

And, what more significant, which value is recommended for production environment?

Answer (score 0):

To compress or not, is decided during [negotiation between the server and client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

Forcing compression would mean that server would send compressed content regardless if client supports it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% sure what's the difference (I'm looking for the same information) but I can definitely say that the "force" value doesn't compress when the client didn't send the relevant Accept-Encoding header, according to a test I just performed (with tomcat 8.0.8). Also, it would make little sense and break so many http clients.

I suppose the difference between "on" and "force" is with the other compression parameters. E.g. "on" would use compressableMimeType and noCompressionUserAgents, whereas "force" would compress ignoring these two parameters (e.g. for all mime types and all user agents).

Answer (score 0):

Actually "force" is only force ***if*** the client supports compression.

Note the force is ***after*** the "Content-Encoding" header check...

```
 /**
 * Check if the resource could be compressed, if the client supports it.
 */
private boolean isCompressible() {

    // Check if content is not already compressed
    MessageBytes contentEncodingMB = response.getMimeHeaders().getValue("Content-Encoding");

    if ((contentEncodingMB != null) &&
            (contentEncodingMB.indexOf("gzip") != -1 ||
                    contentEncodingMB.indexOf("br") != -1)) {
        return false;
    }

    // If force mode, always compress (test purposes only)
    if (compressionLevel == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

[Source](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc8.5.x/trunk/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11Processor.java?view=markup)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the check in useCompression ...

```
    /**
 * Check if compression should be used for this resource. Already checked
 * that the resource could be compressed if the client supports it.
 */
private boolean useCompression() {

    // Check if browser support gzip encoding
    MessageBytes acceptEncodingMB =
        request.getMimeHeaders().getValue("accept-encoding");

    if ((acceptEncodingMB == null)
        || (acceptEncodingMB.indexOf("gzip") == -1)) {
        return false;
    }

    // If force mode, always compress (test purposes only)
    if (compressionLevel == 2) {
        return true;
    }
```